# Problem with Confirmation message when i submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like your help with the following issue:
When I submit a form, I want a message to be shown at the user's side.
The code is running properly, but the alert message after success can't be shown to the user.
Am I missing something?
I believe that something is wrong with the position of my script. Do I have to place it somewhere else in my code or have I some errors?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function save3() {
      var pn = 4; 
      $("#user_id").val(prompt("Give the User Id:"))
      $("#book_id").val(prompt("Give the Book Id:"))
      $("#game_id").val(prompt("Give the Game Id:"))
      $("#site_id").val(pn)
    }
    function load2() {

    }

  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p align="center">example</p>
  <table align="center" width="730">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div>
          <table class="blueTable" style="float: left">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="1"><u>Menu</u></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="New" id="new" onclick="new1()" class="button12" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <form name="SaveGame" id="SaveGame" method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1/PHP/mine2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save" onclick="save3()" class="button12" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id">
                    <input type="hidden" name="book_id" id="book_id">
                    <input type="hidden" name="game_id" id="game_id">
                    <input type="hidden" name="site_id" id="site_id">
                  </form>
                  <script>
                    $("#SaveGame").submit(function(e) {


                      var form = $(this);
                      var url = form.attr('action');

                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                        success: function(data) {
                          alert("The game has been saved!"); // show response from the php script.
                        }
                      });

                      e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
                    });
                    </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

and my php code:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "mysql3");
// Check connection
if($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$user_id =$_POST['user_id'];
$book_id =$_POST['book_id'];
$game_id =$_POST['game_id'];
$site_id =$_POST['site_id'];

    // Attempt insert query execution
if ($result = $link->query("INSERT INTO `components` (`user_id`, `book_id`, `game_id`, `site_id`) VALUES ('$user_id','$book_id','$game_id', '$site_id')") == true)
  echo json_encode($result);
else {
  echo "Error";
}
            //$qry ="INSERT INTO `components` (`user_id`, `book_id`, `game_id`, `site_id`) VALUES ('".$user_id."','".$book_id."','".$game_id."', '".$site_id."')";
  //      if($qry){
    //    mysqli_query($link,$qry);
      //  }

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your server is returning a response to your call? Maybe you're just seeing the request from the client on your server- it needs to send a response back to the client otherwise the success() function won't trigger

Comment: https://jsbin.com/muwusineni/edit?html,output  , i just copy paste your code in jsbin and it seems prompting properly on save click.

Comment: @98mprice the server is returning a simple ok message. i am posting now my php code also...

Comment: You may click 'Run code snippet' now to see it working fine.

Comment: @cjmling yes, but i want an window.alert to the user in order to inform him that the game has been saved. Why the message isn't showing to the user?

Comment: May be it wasn't successfull, try adding `error` callback and alert to see if it was errors. 
` success: function(data) {},
error: function(){
  alert('some error happen');
}`

Comment: @cjmling am i inserted these lines of code ` success: function(data) {}, error: function(){ alert('some error happen'); }` inside the php file?

Comment: @TonyDs  just where there is $.ajax in those html. You already have success, just add the error.

Comment: @TonyDs i've inserted the error function but it doesn't show me an error at the console...Any ideas?